# jquery animate two class at once

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, delay, jquery-callback

I'm having a problem with the `animate()` function. I want to first animate 2 objects, then wait for 4 seconds and animate that object again. My code is like this:

```
//Animation In
$('.show').animate({marginTop : '1px' , opacity: '1px'},1000).delay(4000);
$('.caption').animate({opacity : '1px', top : '20px'},1000).delay(4000);       

//After 4 Second Animation Out       
$('.show').animate({ marginTop : '-200px', opacity:'0px'},1000);
$('.caption').animate({opacity : '0px' , top : '70px'},500,function()
   {         
                fadeInwhipe();// calls This Function
   });
```

This works perfectly for the `.show` class, but sometimes `.caption` animates very fast before `.show`. I've tried to set `.caption` into a callback function of `.show` to prevent `.caption` from animating early, like this:

```
//Animation In
$('.show').animate({marginTop : '1px' , opacity: '1px'},1000).delay(4000);
$('.caption').animate({opacity : '1px', top : '20px'},1000).delay(4000);       

//After 4 Second Animation Out       
$('.show').animate({ marginTop : '-200px', opacity:'0px'},1000 ,function(){
    $('.caption').animate({opacity : '0px' , top : '70px'},500,function()
      {         
                fadeInwhipe();// calls This Function
      });
);
```

But in this case it animates after the `.show` finished. It's executing, but I want to animate both the class at once. Is there any solution? Thanks ...

Comment: Can you include your html and css, or a working example?  Seems to work fine to me  http://jsfiddle.net/6fms5/

Answer (score 0):

Use Queue:false

```
$(function () {
    $("#first").animate({
       width: '200px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#first").animate({
       marginTop: '50px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
});
```

Comment: This is to run two animation on the same element simultaneously.  He is simply trying to run animations on two different elements at the same time.